# How to display the table headers in a row, in angular material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

*My Material table displays the value in below manner:*

**Name |quatity**

Mango|10

```
    <div class="table-cover center-table">
      <div class="mat-elevation-z8 elevation-scroll-control">
        <table mat-table class="full-width-table left-margin" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">

          <!-- Name Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Name</td>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="">
              <div class="cell-style padding-left">{{row.Name}}</div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- quantity Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
            <td mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>quantity</td>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <div class="cell-style">{{row.quantity}}</div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"> </tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"> </tr>
        </table>

      </div>      
    </div>
```

*But I want to display the value like below:*

**Name** | Mango

**quatity** | 10

*How can I achieve this? any help is much appreciated*

Comment: Arrange you element and data as given in this link https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz demo for the problem ?

Answer (score 5):

You may do that by:

1. Transposing your data from columns to row:

   `Before:
    Mango |10
    Banana|5`

   `After:
   Mango|Banana
   10|5`
2. Including the labels as the first column of your data:

   `Name|Mango|Banana
    Quantity|10|5`
3. Adjust your table to display columns dynamically (so that you may have any number of columns), as on this example from [angular material table documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples):

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

4. If not required you may remove the header row
5. If you want to format the first column, you may use some css as:

   `td.mat-cell:nth-child(1) {
     // formatting
   }`
6. Also, if required, you may use property sticky of MatColumnDef to keep the first column sticky (in this case you may want to have the first column separate from the dynamic *ngFor loop, so that you may easily have only the first column sticky)

I've created a working [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjskob)

Comment: Thank you for your response @GCSDC. I tried your solution but it still not displaying the expected result. Can please alter my code for better understanding.

Comment: @Rajath I've included a working stackblitz example on my answer. Please let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more concern - if we do like that, then it becomes very difficult to update the data in the table(database) right? How we can address this issue.

Comment: Not sure if I got your point, but if you need the data on the initial format, you may just transpose it again.