# How to display table headers in a column Angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, tabular, mat-table

Creating a table for a single user and I want to use Angular Material (mat-table).

Here is what I'm looking for in my table:

```
Username    | becky123
First Name  | becky
Last Name   | stewart
```

Notice that the headers are in 1 column instead of your typical row like I've seen in most of the Material table documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

Also the User object is basically the data source in the ts file (it's not an array since it's just a singular user.) Could someone please help me achieve this?

I've seen this [How to display the table headers in a row, in angular material table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493197/how-to-display-the-table-headers-in-a-row-in-angular-material-table) but this would be assuming that I have multiple users when I only have one stored in an object.

I really appreciate it.